# Save a macro just created in vimrc

Tags: macro

Sometimes I create macros. Sometimes I create the same macro multiple times.

Sometimes I get tired of creating the same macro over again. Can I store macros? Can I load a preset of macros? Can I make a macro and save it forever?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can! There are a couple ways to do this. By default, all registers will be saved into your *viminfo* file, and loaded once you start vim. This is the easiest way. However, it's not foolproof. Each register will be lost if you accidentally record/yank over it.

The better way to save a specific macro is to put it in your `.vimrc`. For example, let's say you want `foo` to be saved into macro `a`. This could be achieved with:

```
let @a='foo'
```

in your vimrc. If you have your macros already made, you could type

```
ilet @a='<C-r><C-r>a'<esc>
```

to paste the current contents of the macro, if you don't feel like typing it all out again.

---

*Thanks to Andrew Keeton for pointing out `<C-r><C-r>`*

Comment: You'll probably want to use `<C-r><C-r>` (two, instead of one) to [insert the text literally](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R)

Comment: @AndrewKeeton Ooh, great improvement. Thanks for letting me know about that

Comment: `<c-r><c-r>` won't work if your macro contains special key sequence such as `<c-right>`, `"ap` don't have this problem.

Comment: note you can map the string, e.g. `nnoremap <Leader>fo foo' in your vimrc so that you establish a direct keybinding. The advantage is that you keep your registers clean.

Comment: An advice I give all you is to use double quotes so you can use things like `\<c-a>\<esc>`, otherwise your control characters must be typed literally.