# How do you read the contents of a macro into your buffer?

Tags: buffers, macro, register

I know that you can use `let @x = @w` to copy the contents of a macro from one register to another, but how do you read the contents of your macro register into the buffer?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/save-a-macro-just-created-in-vimrc, although I think DBK's answer is better.

Comment: @dedowsdi that doesnt seem like a dupe at all, though def related.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `read a macro into buffer` and `save a macro in vimrc` are basically the same thing.

Comment: Disagree, maybe pedantically—one involves the let and the “saving,” whereas here we might just care about pasting. @dedowsdi but good to link them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are stored in the same registers as you use for yanking, deleting, and putting, so any of

```
"ap
:put a
```

Etc